# adding calendar view in ios application development

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I want to display a calendar view when user clicks on calendar icon.

For iPhone its OK, I can display a calendar that is having the same look and feel in iPhone.

But when it displays in iPad, the view is as same like iPhone calendar instead of displaying the default iPad calendar view.

What we can do to display the default iPad calendar view when running in iPad simulator or iPad device.?

Comment: How can create same look & feel calendar in ios, can u let me know ?????

Answer (score 0):

iPhone and iPad have different screen dimensions. So you will have to detect on what your app runs and change the frame of your calendar view to be of approximate width and height.

Comment: problem is not with the width and height. in iPad the calender view entirely different from what we are seen in iPhone device. The entire look and feel is different for iPad calender . I want to display the default calender view in iPad when running app in iPad

Comment: You can not use the Calendar view that comes part of iPad in your App. THere is no SDK Level support. can you share screen shots of the calendar you are using in iPhone.?